# Android aFreeRDP cmake build failed

Tags: android, linux, freerdp

I tried to build aFreeRDP app for android.

I followed the instructions up to `ldconfig` described in [compilation page](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/Compilation).

After that I ran below commands and no one works. And showing that build failed.

```
./scripts/android-build-freerdp.sh
```

or

```
./scripts/android-build-freerdp.sh --ndk $ANDROID_NDK --sdk $ANDROID_SDK
```

**Output in terminal:**

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    ANDROID_ABI
    CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE


-- Build files have been written to: /home/sufi/FreeRDP
/home/sufi/FreeRDP/build/freerdp-build/armeabi
[RUN] cmake --build . --target install
Error: could not load cache
[ERROR] cmake --build . --target install retured 1
```

Then I ran `./gradlew build` to create an apk and it gives me below error when tries to connect with a remote connection:

```
com.freerdp.afreerdp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.freerdp.freerdpcore.services.LibFreeRDP.freerdp_new:(Landroid/content/Context;)J
at com.freerdp.freerdpcore.services.LibFreeRDP.freerdp_new(Native Method)
at com.freerdp.freerdpcore.services.LibFreeRDP.newInstance(LibFreeRDP.java:116)
at com.freerdp.freerdpcore.application.GlobalApp.createSession(GlobalApp.java:128)
at com.freerdp.freerdpcore.presentation.SessionActivity.connect(SessionActivity.java:661)
at com.freerdp.freerdpcore.presentation.SessionActivity.processIntent(SessionActivity.java:651)
```

What have I missed?

Thanks is advance.

I tried on `ubuntu 16.04`

Openssl version : `OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `CMakeCache.txt` just solved my issue.

Special thanks to `Zhifeng Hu`

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319292/cmake-error-could-not-load-cache)