# How do I create a Python package wrapper around C libraries that can be installed via pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmake, pip, python-packaging

I have not had much luck with this question:

[How do you compile a C library with multiple dependencies into a Python package? Cmake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709217/how-do-you-compile-a-c-library-with-multiple-dependencies-into-a-python-package)

I have a python package with functions which wrap around several C libraries. I have done this with ctypes, linking to the C libraries installed via `sudo make` within `/usr/local/lib`

However, this is not the best solution. Those C libraries should be installed when the python package is installed via github or pip, correct? Currently, these C libraries each require cmake.

How do you compile the C libraries upon installation of the python package? Is there another recommended way to distribute python packages which wrap around C functions?