# Why `ld: library not found for -lstdc++` when I package my python binding for a c++ library using pybind11

Tags: python, c++, cmake, pip, pybind11

I want to package my `python binding` for a `c++ library` using `pybind11` and upload it to `pip`. It's easy to run `Cmake` and `make` to compile the binding project individually.
However, when I use python setup.py, Cmake throws `ld: library not found for -lstdc++` on my `Mac Mojave`.

1. I've tried `xcode-select --install`
2. And `open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg`
   Both of them installed properly.
3. Also, I've tried `sudo python setup.py sdist build` and then `python setup.py sdist build`, amazingly it did work! But the the same error throws when I download and compile from `pip install my-package`.
4. Strangly, I used anaconda `python3.6` on two Mac, it failed both, I create new conda env `py3.7`, It installed successfully!!! I also used /usr/local/bin/python3 (3.4) and also succeed!!!

My setup.py is like this:

```py
import os
import sys
import pathlib

from setuptools import setup, Extension
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext as build_ext_orig

class CMakeExtension(Extension):
    def __init__(self, name):
        # don't invoke the original build_ext for this special extension
        super().__init__(name, sources=[])

class build_ext(build_ext_orig):
    def run(self):
        for ext in self.extensions:
            self.build_cmake(ext)
        super().run()

    def build_cmake(self, ext):
        # example of build args
        build_args = ['--config', 'Release', '--', '-j4']

        cwd = pathlib.Path().absolute()
        build_temp = pathlib.Path(self.build_temp)
        build_temp.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

        os.chdir(str(build_temp))
        self.spawn(['cmake', str(cwd)])
        if not self.dry_run:
            self.spawn(['cmake', '--build', '.'] + build_args)
        os.chdir(str(cwd))

setup(
    ...
    install_requires=['numpy', 'pybind11'],
    include_package_data=True,
    ext_modules=[CMakeExtension('xxx')],
    cmdclass={
        'build_ext': build_ext,
    }
)
```

which I mostly copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/48015772/7961269

And my CMakeLists.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(xxx)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++")

find_package(pybind11 REQUIRED)
include_directories(...)
pybind11_add_module(xxx xxx/xxx.cpp)
```

Hope I can `pip install my-package` successfully without any errors

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpybind11%5D+ld%3A+library+not+found+for+%22-lstdc%2B%2B%22

Comment: For Mojave the setting [should be](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10135#issuecomment-426736042) `10.14`.

Comment: thank you @phd, It did work!!! But is there a way to tell pip automatically set this value if needed?

Comment: No idea. Perhaps not as it's a `clang`'s trick, not `pip`'s.

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that something in the python build is automatically adding `-lstdc++` to the compiler flags, but because you've told clang to use `-stdlib=libc++` it isn't looking in the directory that contains libstdc++ (which is correct, because you told it not to use libstdc++).

I think the python build system is not compatible with libc++, or you need to find some way to tell it to stop adding `-lstdc++` automatically.