# How to convert a Python .pyd file to a wheel on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, pybind11

I am wondering how to convert `.pyd` file to a [Python Wheel](https://pythonwheels.com/)?

Environment: on Windows, I have compiled a set of C++ files to a `.pyd` file using [MSVC 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/) and [CMake](https://cmake.org/). I am using [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11) to create a Python module.

I have tried every technique I can possibly think of over the past few months.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42585210/extending-setuptools-extension-to-use-cmake-in-setup-py

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by using the [answer by @hoefling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42585210/extending-setuptools-extension-to-use-cmake-in-setup-py):

- Created a `setup.py` file from said answer, filled in the blanks.
- Then used this batch file:

```
@echo off
rem Build and install module. Run in a Visual Studio x64 prompt.
rem Out of the box, Python does not support building of wheels.
pip install wheel 
rem Build wheel.
python setup.py bdist_wheel
rem Install wheel.
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall dist/MyProject-0.0.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
pause
```

The final boss to slay was working out, after a week, that if `CMakeCache.txt`  is present in the root directory, everything will fail with a huge 20-line nonsensical error message. `CMake` is a reasonable build system, but it sure has some absolutely horrific bugs - there's no other word for that sort of behavior.

---

### Appendix A

Quote from [Building C and C++ Extensions](https://docs.python.org/3.8/extending/building.html):

> A C extension for CPython is a shared library (e.g. a .so file on Linux, .pyd on Windows), which exports an initialization function.
>
> To be importable, the shared library must be available on PYTHONPATH, and must be named after the module name, with an appropriate extension. When using distutils, the correct filename is generated automatically.
>
> The initialization function has the signature:
>
> ```
> PyObject* PyInit_modulename(void)
> ```
>
> It returns either a fully-initialized module, or a PyModuleDef instance. See Initializing C modules for details.

So during development, it is not really that necessary to compile the `.pyd` file into a wheel for installation. As long as the `.pyd` file is available on`PYTHONPATH`, and it named correctly, then everything will just work.