# Building CMake extension with pip

Tags: python, c++, cmake, pip, setup.py

I'm working on a C++/Python project with the following structure:

```
foo
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
├── source
└── python
    ├── foo
    │   ├── _foo_py.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── setup.py
    └── source
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        └── _foo_cpp.cpp
```

`foo/source` and `foo/include` contain C++ source files and `foo/python/source/_foo_cpp.cpp` contains pybind11 wrapper code for this C++ code. Running `setup.py` is supposed to build the C++ code (by running CMake), create a `_foo_cpp` Python module in the form of a shared object and integrate it with the Python code in `_foo_py.py`. I.e. I want to be able to simply call `python setup.py install` from `foo/python` to install the `foo` module to my system. I'm currently using a CMake extension class in `setup.py` to make this work:

```
class CMakeExtension(Extension):
    def __init__(self, name, sourcedir):
        Extension.__init__(self, name, sources=[])
        self.sourcedir = os.path.abspath(sourcedir)


class CMakeBuild(build_ext):
    def run(self):
        try:
            subprocess.check_output(['cmake', '--version'])
        except OSError:
            raise RuntimeError("cmake command must be available")

        for ext in self.extensions:
            self.build_extension(ext)

    def build_extension(self, ext):
        if not os.path.exists(self.build_temp):
            os.makedirs(self.build_temp)

        self._setup(ext)
        self._build(ext)

    def _setup(self, ext):
        cmake_cmd = [
            'cmake',
            ext.sourcedir,
        ]

        subprocess.check_call(cmake_cmd, cwd=self.build_temp)

    def _build(self, ext):
        cmake_build_cmd = [
            'cmake',
            '--build', '.',
        ]

        subprocess.check_call(cmake_build_cmd, cwd=self.build_temp)
```

The problem arises when I try to directly call `pip` in `foo/python`, e.g. like this:

```
pip wheel -w wheelhouse --no-deps .
```

It seems that before running the code in `setup.py`, `pip` copies the content of the working directory into a temporary directory. This obviously doesn't include the C++ code and the top-level `CMakeLists.txt`. That in turn causes `CMakeBuild._setup` to fail because there is seemingly no way to obtain a path to the `foo` root directory from inside `setup.py` after it has been copied to another location by `pip`.

Is there anything I can do to make this setup work with both `python` and `pip`? I have seen some approaches that first run `cmake` to generate a `setup.py` from a `setup.py.in` to inject package version, root directory path etc. but I would like to avoid this and have `setup.py` call `cmake` instead of the other way around.

Comment: You are probably not including extension sources/`CMakeLists.txt` in the source dist.

Comment: @hoefling How do I do that? Via an option to `setup`? Which one?

Comment: https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html

Comment: @hoefling I have thought about using `package_data` but I don't see how to do that here. I.e. by setting `package_dir={"": ".."}` and `package_data={"": "CMakeLists.txt"}`? That doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You can also use the code from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48015772/2650249) which will just work.