# how to install compiled C-extension module (.so file) in setup.py?

Tags: python, setuptools

The [official page](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/extending.html) seems to require me use `Extension`, listing all compile details inside `setup.py`. While I prefer to do the compilation through cmake.

Is there any way to install compiled extension module like `.so`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48015772/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+cmake

Comment: I wonder if there is an easy way to do. phd's answer requires too much effort beyond what I need here. @AhmedAEK It doesn't work in editable mode, I think it's acceptable due to simplest, though.