# Python/pip: How to do an editable package install with extension modules?

Tags: python, cmake, pip, pybind11, extension-modules

I am developing a python package with a C++ extension module that interops with the python code via pybind11, and which I am building using CMake (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42585210/extending-setuptools-extension-to-use-cmake-in-setup-py) answer).

I have the package installed as editable to aid in development via `pip install -e .`

I frequently update the C++ extension module, and each time I do so, the only way to get my changes to work has been to completely clean every build file, uninstall, then re-install the package, which mostly defeats the purpose of having an editable install for development purposes.

Is there a way to do an editable install with extension modules such that I can rebuild the module when I make changes to it without cleaning and reinstalling the whole package each time?