# Can pip install editable avoid recompiling from sratch?

Tags: python, cmake, pip, setup.py, pybind11

I'm developing a [python module](https://github.com/libigl/libigl-python-bindings/) with a long pybind11 C++ extension compilation step invoked via cmake in `setup.py`.

When making changes to a C++ file, cmake invoked via `python setup.py develop` will avoid recompiling units whose dependent files have not changed. However, invoking `setup.py` directly ignores the settings in my `pyproject.toml` and I understand that the modern way to do a developmental build is with `python -m pip install -e .`

While `pip install -e` successfully builds, it unfortunately starts from scratch inside a clean temporary directory every invocation. Is there a way to instruct `pip install -e` to maintain my CMakeCache.txt and compilation dependency tracking?

(And/or does this somehow indicate that I misunderstand `pip install -e` or am using it incorrectly?)

*This [previous unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73849192/python-pip-how-to-do-an-editable-package-install-with-extension-modules) is quite similar sounding. Perhaps, I have the added detail that my `python setup.py develop` is working in this regard.*

Comment: I'd use ccache instead.

Comment: I've never used ccache before. Do you have any pointers on how to get started mixing it with pip install?

Comment: Since you're invoking CMake, you can use the `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=ccache` CMake flag.