# Every call to configure_file fails on WSL: configure_file Problem configuring file

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've just built and installed cmake 3.16 on a fresh WSL install (Ubuntu18.04 LTS). I then created a default hello world project

```
(base) ciaran@DESKTOP-K0APGUV:/mnt/d/ATest$ tree .
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── main.cpp
```

```
//CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(ATest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(ATest main.cpp)
```

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <string>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And then tried to build:

```
(base) ciaran@DESKTOP-K0APGUV:/mnt/d/ATest$ mkdir build
(base) ciaran@DESKTOP-K0APGUV:/mnt/d/ATest$ cd build/
(base) ciaran@DESKTOP-K0APGUV:/mnt/d/ATest/build$ cmake ..
```

And I get the following.

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:185 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.1.0
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:212 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.1.0
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:210 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:80 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:73 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/mnt/d/ATest/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/mnt/d/ATest/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
(base) ciaran@DESKTOP-K0APGUV:/mnt/d/ATest/build$
```

I originally tried cmake 3.15 but upgraded to see if it was a version problem, given this, I don't this it is. I've also tried `g++-7` and `g++-9` which behave the same.

Does anybody know what might be going on here? Thanks.

Comment: Definitely not a GCC problem, it doesn't get that far. WSL suggests that the CMakeListst.txt fle may be in DOS format (CRLF), not Unix. `dos2unix CMakeLists.txt` would fix that.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought of that. I tried running `dos2unix CMakeLists.txt` and rebuilding from clean build directory and I got the same problem.

Comment: Googling the issue led me to this [post](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4257#issuecomment-507799403) describing a similar problem with a potential solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Create a file named `wsl.conf` in /etc/ with the following text:

```
# /etc/wsl.conf
[automount]
options = "metadata"
enabled = true
```

2. Reboot wsl:

`wsl.exe -t Ubuntu // (or other e.g. Debian)`

Sources:

- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003413779-Troubles-with-WSL-toolchain-Test-CMake-run-finished-with-errors-
- https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3994#issuecomment-507864837
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config

Comment: This didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Yes this fixed it. The link posted by @squareskittles lead me to the same information. For completeness I'm going to post the solution.

Comment: In fact, since you've just updated your answer with the solution, I won't repost the solution.

Comment: This worked very well. Could you please explain why this works? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix the above error by running the following commands in order:

```
% cd build
% cmake -B . -S ..
% cmake --build .
```

This solution is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74338548/20434107).