# CMake has to be run twice, the first time always fails

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, cmake, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running cmake on win10 WSL with ubuntu20.04, apt-get installed cmake and used the simpliest CMakeLists.txt as below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(my)
add_executable(testConst01 testConst.c01)
```

Run `mkdir build; cd build; cmake ../my` it will give a bunch of error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:185 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:212 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:210 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:80 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:73 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/mnt/d/my/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/mnt/d/my/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Then I run cmake the second time, everything become ok, and `make` command will generate all I wanted. Then I `rm -fr` the `build` dir, do the job again. First time it fails and second time it succeeds. Always like this.

I took a look at the CMakeOutput.log and CMakeError.log file, didn't find any real error message either.

What is the cause of this problem, how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: How do you expect cmake to interpret a file with the file ending `.c01`? Why are you using such an unconventional file name?

Comment: Also, what do the mentioned log files say?

Answer (score 1):

Finnaly I found this was WSL config issue, not cmake problem, as stated in this thread:

[Every call to configure_file fails on WSL: configure_file Problem configuring file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62879479/every-call-to-configure-file-fails-on-wsl-configure-file-problem-configuring-fi)

Step to fix:
In wsl command line window, `sudo vi /etc/wsl.conf`
add these lines:

```
options = "metadata"
enabled = true
```

Then close all wsl windows.

Then in cmd.exe or powershell, restart my linux instance. E.g. I'm using Ubuntu20.04 I'll
`wsl -t Ubuntu20.04`

Then run my cmake job, everything is OK now.